# NIC usage - who is using this connection

Tags: linux, suse

Is there a way to see who is using NIC connections,

I have to NIC connected on same VLAN, but only one is supposed to used my users,...I want to check who is logged in using other NIC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
iftop -i interface
```

to display bandwidth usage on an interface.